# Backgroundworker ReportProgress event does not fire

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I've a backgroundworker which take care of a timer in my application. This is the code:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Inizializzo il backgroundworker 
        bgwTimer.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgwTimer.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bgwTimer.DoWork += (bgwTimer_DoWork);
        bgwTimer.RunWorkerCompleted +=(bgwTimer_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgwTimer.ProgressChanged += (bgwTimer_ProgressChanged);
    }

    void bgwTimer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void bgwTimer_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Basically the event "ProgressChanged" is never fired and so I cannot update the status of a progressbar.
The event DoWork is linked to this method:

```
    void bgwTimer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (bgwTimer.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            while (bgwTimer.IsBusy)
            {                
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                bgwTimer.ReportProgress(i);
                refreshTimer();
            }
        }
    }
```

By my side the code looks good and it runs fine. As you can see the ReportProgress method is called but the event is not fired. Any hints?

UPDATE:
Whops! I found that the event "bgwTimer_ProgressChanged" is fired only if I run the RunWorkerAsync right after the declaration of event. Basically:

bgwTimer.ProgressChanged += (bgwTimer_ProgressChanged);
bgwTimer.RunWorkerAsync(); //this works!

Since I run the worker when the user press a button, the event is not triggered.

---

Here's the code of click event button:

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        this.TopMost = true;
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
        progressBar1.Step = 0;

        if (_bgwTimer.IsBusy)
            _bgwTimer.CancelAsync();
        else
            _bgwTimer.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: You don't increase the value of i - maybe thats the reason the event is not raised?

Comment: A reference that may help (I couldn't find your issue though) is here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker

Comment: Robert, the timer basically update the Text property of a label, nothing else.

Comment: That may be an issue.  As per the link I posted, you're only supposed to update UI elements in certain threads, which the BGW is not in, hence the ProgressChanged event in the first place, which helps get around this.  I wonder if this behavior is causing other "interesting" behavior?

Comment: In your edit, you said that it didn't work when using a button to trigger it.  Do you Sleep the thread that the button click event is processed in?  If so, you've suspended the UI thread (bad) and nothing else can get through.  Heck, your "finished" method `bgwTimer_RunWorkerCompleted` wouldn't run either.  Please post your original "button clicked event" method.  I think that'll reveal the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a breakpoint, or a `Debug.Print` or `System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox` just before `bgwTimer.ReportProgress(i)`, to verify that you're actually entering the `while` loop.

Note that the `BackgroundWorker` is not actually a timer; it's a wrapper for a thread that provides a threadsafe invoking layer for your user interface.

Your `if (bgwTimer.CancellationPending) { }` should be inside the `while` loop, not outside it.  It will only get checked once in your current code.

Note that, if you're inside the `DoWork` event handler, then by definition you're running an asynchronous process, so `IsBusy` should always be true (according to the MSDN documentation), and therefore your `while` is an infinite loop.  But check it with your debugger.

Answer (score 3):

It's not raising the event because the value of `i` is always zero, which is helpfully undocumented but I found out the same thing when building a background worker a while back.

Comment: Whops! I've added the increase of "i" variables, but the event is not triggered

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to start the worker.  Add this line to your OnLoad() method:

```
   bgwTimer.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: +1 for a very nice observation, it was in fact omitted which can only leave you to assume the worker is never even started.

Comment: Sorry guys, I omit this line in the posted code but I've in in my code. I fire the RunWorker when the user press a button.

Comment: So there's important code involved with this problem that you didn't post.  We can't look over your shoulder from here.

Answer (score 0):

In the DoWork-Method replace bgwTimer through ((BackgroundWorker)sender). Maybe this is the problem